# Using XSL to display content from two Sharepoint Lists

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to use XSL to display content from two Sharepoint 2010 lists.

The first list is a simple Personnel List (name, title, personnel pic and a brief summary of a person). This is a straightforward call of the information from the Sharepoint list and works perfect.

Here is where things get tricky.

I have another list (a Sharepoint Picture Library) in which I have 6 brand images.

I want to display a random brand image from the Picture Library with the Personnel Information so that every time the page is refreshed, we see the Personnel Information with a random brand image.

The trouble I am having is 1). calling the Picture Library into the XSL and 2). randomizing the content.

If anyone can make sense out of what I am trying to do and can offer advice I would greatly appreciate it.

-- EDIT --

Here is the XSL code I am using. I tried using a response.write method but it blows up the Sharepoint webpart. Same with javascript (which I would be happy with) but it either doesn't work or causes the Sharepoint webpart to implode on itself:

```
    <xsl:template name="OurStudents" match="Row[@Style='OurStudents']" mode="itemstyle">
     <xsl:variable name="LinkTarget">
        <xsl:if test="@OpenInNewWindow = 'True'" >_blank</xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
      <div id="body" style="margin:5px 5px 15px 5px; padding:5px; width:95%; background-image:url('../../students/PublishingImages/profiles-bg.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; background-color:#fff;">
        <table>
        <thead>
        <div style="border:1px solid #616365; background-color:#ebebeb; padding: 5px; margin:5px;">
        <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:12pt; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; color:#616365;"><xsl:if test="string-length(@Name) != 0"><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></xsl:if></span>
        <span style="font-style:italic; font-size:10pt; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;"><xsl:if test="string-length(@Website) != 0">(Program of Study: <a href="{substring-before(@Website,',')}" target="{$LinkTarget}" title="{@Program} Webpage"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="(@Program)"/><xsl:text></xsl:text></a>)</xsl:if></span>
        </div>
        </thead>

        <tr>
        <td>    
        <div id="photo" style="margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #000; width:width:95%; text-align:center; background-image:url('../../students/PublishingImages/profiles-reverse-bg.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; background-color:#867e89;">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@Picture != ''">
                    <img style="border:1px solid #867e89; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; width:200px;" src="{substring-before(@Picture,',')}" /> 
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <img style="border:1px solid #867e89; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; width:125px;" src="http://www.swgc.mun.ca/PublishingImages/no-pic.jpg" alt="Picture Not Available"/>              
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        <br></br>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div style="margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; padding:5px; border:1px solid #000; width:94%; height:32%; background-color:#fff;">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(@About) != 0"><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="@About"/></xsl:if>
        </div>


<![CDATA[

<%Response.Write(string.Format("<img src='{0}/students/ERWords/{1}.jpg'/>",Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.Site.Url,new System.Random().Next(1,6)));%>


]]>


        <img src="../../SiteAssets/Images/logos/Grenfell-logo-nu.png" width="200px" hspace="10" vspace="10" style="margin: 200px 5px 25px 250px;"></img>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr></hr>   
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you add some code? The XML sources, the XSLT you wrote and the expected result?

Comment: This is typically a task where I would implement a Javascript solution instead, or possibly build an external contenttype handling the logic.

Comment: I have added the code I am using to my original post.